# Ember.js - different promise classes

Tags: ember.js, rsvp.js, rsvp-promise

What is the difference between using:

`new RSVP.Promise()` ([docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.html))

and

`new Promise()` ([docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.Promise.html))

in an Ember app?

Are they just aliases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one creates a new RSVP promise. RSVP promises are ES6/A+ compliant, so it's essentially a polyfill (with some extra features). Nothing wrong with doing this method.

The second case depends on the scope where the code is called. If you have a `var Promise = RSVP.Promise;` somewhere, they mean the same thing. However, if you haven't declared `Promise` yourself, this will likely fall back to the browser implementation (if one exists). Because RSVP is ES6/A+ compliant, you likely wouldn't notice if the browser implementation is used (unless you're using custom RSVP methods).

Short answer long: they might mean the same thing, but they might not.

Personally, I like the second method better because when RSVP is removed and the browser implementation is used, no code will have to change. I just do `window.Promise = window.Promise || Ember.RSVP.Promise` at the start of my script as a polyfill. But if you do that, be sure to only use the methods listed on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), not any extra RSVP methods.